# How can I shift a line down in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

How can I shift a line down in shell, based on it's line number?

For an example file ex.file,

```
stuff
other stuff
I want this line to go down one
more stuff
more stuff
```

I would want this file to be changed so that it reads:

```
stuff
other stuff
more stuff
I want this line to go down one
more stuff
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk -v n=3 'NR==n{line=$0; next} NR==n+2{print line} 1' file

stuff
other stuff
more stuff
I want this line to go down one
more stuff
```

To save changes back to file using gnu awk:

```
awk -i inplace -v n=3 'NR==n{line=$0; next} NR==n+2{print line} 1' file
```

If not using gnu awk then

```
awk -v n=3 'NR==n{line=$0; next} NR==n+2{print line} 1' file > _file.tmp &&
mv _file.tmp file
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Where do you specify line `3`? I need to be able to do this for any line number, not including the last line.

Comment: You can pass any line number in the command line option, e.g. `-v n=5` for line #5

Comment: How do I overwrite the contents of `ex.file`?

Comment: Using gnu awk you can do: `awk -i inplace -v n=3 'NR==n{line=$0; next} NR==n+2{print line} 1' file`

Comment: If not using gnu awk then `awk -v n=3 'NR==n{line=$0; next} NR==n+2{print line} 1' file > _file.tmp && mv _file.tmp file`

Comment: Perhaps we should move this comment to the answer's body

Answer (score 2):

Using sed:

```
$ sed '3{h;d}; 4{p;x}' file
stuff
other stuff
more stuff
I want this line to go down one
more stuff
```

`3{h;d}` tells sed to save line 3 in the hold space (`h`) and skip to the next line without printing (`d`).

`4{p;x}` tells sed to print line 4 (`p`), then retrieve the line in the hold space (line 3) so that it can be printed (`x`).

To overwrite the file in place:

```
sed -i.bak '3{h;d}; 4{p;x}' file
```

#### Alternative

Using GNU sed (gsed on OSX):

```
$ sed -E '3 {N; s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2\n\1/}' file
stuff
other stuff
more stuff
I want this line to go down one
more stuff
```

On line 3, this tells sed to append the next line (line 4) to the pattern space and then a substitution command is performed to swap the order of the two lines.

Comment: Thank you. How can I incorporate overwriting `ex.file` in these commands?

Comment: @kilojoules With `sed`, to overwrite the file, use the `-i.bak` option.  (That will create a backup file with a `.bak` extension.  If you don't want that, then you need to tell me which OS you are on.)